# java.lang.SecurityException: no manifiest section for signature file

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have been working on a **javafx** application. I have some libraries added in my project and the application runs perfectly. But when i am trying to make a jar file of the project and run that file its giving me errors.

## Error Log:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: no manifiest section for signature file entry org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/JDKMessageDigest$RIPEMD256.class
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.verifySection(SignatureFileVerifier.java:440)
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:295)
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:238)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:316)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:228)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:383)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:450)
    at sun.misc.JarIndex.getJarIndex(JarIndex.java:137)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:839)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:831)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(URLClassPath.java:830)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(URLClassPath.java:803)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:530)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:520)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:519)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:492)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getNextLoader(URLClassPath.java:457)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:211)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:365)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main"
```

I don't know which jar file its indicating and how should i solve it. Btw i am developing it in **intellij** and i have followed other solutions of this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9594412/2356808 but i couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Java SecurityException no manifiest section for signature file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48755420/java-securityexception-no-manifiest-section-for-signature-file?noredirect=1#comment87825362_48755420); Possible duplicate [Maven shade jar throw exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302022/maven-shade-jar-throw-exception)

Comment: Additional supporting question [Error while creating consolidated jar file - no manifiest section for signature file entry javax/mail/internet/ContentDisposition.class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592057/error-while-creating-consolidated-jar-file-no-manifiest-section-for-signature/20522281) and [java.lang.SecurityException: no manifest section for signature file entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045744/java-lang-securityexception-no-manifest-section-for-signature-file-entry)